# Using jQuery autocomplete on multiple fields in the same web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, autocomplete

To all readers, please don't just assume this is a duplicate because there are other people who have posted questions that also relate to setting up jQuery autocomplete to work on multiple fields in the same page.  I've spent time looking at lots of pages like that, but none of them are any help with my problem.

Those other pages usually discuss having 2 or 3 fields working with autocomplete in the same page.  In my scenario I already have 4 fields working with autocomplete in the same page without problem, but when I tried setting up an additional 3 fields to work with autocomplete (taking my total to 7), autocomplete simply wouldn't work for fields 5,6 and 7.

It looks to me as though autocomplete just doesn't work, when you use it too many times in the same page.  Therefore, if anyone has any suggestions for resolving that problem (so that I can get a 5th, 6th and 7th field to work with autocomplete) please let me know.

Also, with my problem I am using standard jQuery code in the same way on all the fields. However, for fields 5, 6 and 7 it just doesn't want to work.

I have given some code below to show what I'm using.  This is code that actually works on my first 4 fields without problem, but just doesn’t on the last 3.  The code gets potential matches to user input from a database table and inserts it into the list that's used for autocomplete.

Also, I have actually tried a simple copy and paste of the code from a field where it does work to one of the fields where it doesn't work.  I assumed that the autocomplete would work when I did that, but it would just give me the wrong potential matches, because it was using the wrong database table.  However, it still didn't work when I did that, so it does look like an issue where the code just doesn't work when I'm using it too many times in the same page.

Therefore, if anyone knows of a way of resolving this problem, please let me know.  Big thanks in advance for any help.

HTML code that deals with one of the actual fields that works with autocomplete:

```
<tr>
    <td align='right'><font color='#FFFFFF'>&nbsp;Position</font></td>
    <td align='left'>
        <input id="autocomplete_contact_position" name='contact_position' style='field_class' value='<?php
        if (isset($_POST['contact_position']))
            echo $_POST['contact_position']; ?>' />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Code from sites index.php file that responds to input to the 'contact_position' field:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() { $( "#autocomplete_contact_position" ).autocomplete ( { source: '/contacts/get_contact_positions.php' } ); } );
</script>
```

'get_contact_positions.php' file that gets the potential match data from the database, so that it can be displayed in the autocomplete list:

```
<?php
$dbHost = '???.??.??.??';
$dbUsername = '????';
$dbPassword = '????';
$dbName = 'contacts';
//connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

//get matched data from database
$query = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT contact_position FROM contact_company WHERE contact_position LIKE '".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY contact_position ASC");

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
    $data[] = $row['contact_position'];

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

As I've said above, the code I'm showing does work on my first 4 fields, but doesn't on the last 3.  I'm genuinely doing things in the same way across all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

i am having a pure vanilla javascript solutions for this try this

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Autosuggest</title>
  <style>
    #autosuggest{
      position: relative;
      width: 400px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    #autosuggest input{
      height: 40px;
      border:1px solid #eee;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0 2%;

    }
    #autosuggest input:focus{
      outline: none;
    }
    #autosuggest ul{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 39px;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 0px;
      max-height: 200px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    #autosuggest ul li{
      padding: 5px;
      border:1px solid #eee;
      border-top: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>

<form action=""> 
<div id="autosuggest">
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value, 'txtHint', this.id)">
<ul id="txtHint"></ul>
</div>

<div id="autosuggest">
<input type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="showHint(this.value, 'txtHint2', this.id)">
<ul id="txtHint2"></ul>
</div>

<div id="autosuggest">
<input type="text" id="txt3" onkeyup="showHint(this.value, 'txtHint3', this.id)">
<ul id="txtHint3"></ul>
</div>
</form>

<script>
function showHint(str, id, current_id) {
  var xhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q="+str+"&id="+current_id, true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
// set value of txt1
function sendToInput(str, id, current_id) {
  document.getElementById(id).value = str;
  document.getElementById(current_id).innerHTML = "";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**gethint.php**

```
<?php
$a = [
'Mira Road',
'Chembur',
'Andheri West',
'Kharghar',
'Malad West',
'Andheri East',
'Bandra West',
'Goregaon West',
'Kandivali East',
'Ghodbunder Road',
'Navi Mumbai',
'Bhandup West',
'Borivali West',
'Panvel',
'Khar East',
'Kandivali West',
'Goregaon East',
'90 Feet Road',
'Nelson Manickam Road',
'Abdul Rehman Street',
'Agripada',
'Airoli',
'Airoli Sector 4',
'Airoli Sector 8',
'Altamount Road',
'Ambarnath',
'Ambarnath East',
'Ambernath West',
'Amboli',
'Andheri Kurla Road',
'Andheri Sahar Road',
'Antop Hill',
'Apollo Bunder',
'August Kranti Maidan',
'Babulnath Road',
'Badlapur',
'Ballard Estate',
'Bandra East',
'Belapur',
'Bhandup',
'Bhandup East',
'Bhayandar',
'Bhayandar East',
'Bhayandar Wada',
'Bhayandar West',
'Bhayander',
'Bhayander East',
'Bhayander West',
'Bhindi Bazaar',
'Bhiwandi',
'Bhiwandi',
'Bhoiwada',
'Bhulabhai Desai Road',
'Bhuleshwar',
'Bhyandar East',
'Boisar',
'Boisar West',
'Borivali',
'Borivali East',
'Breach Candy',
'Byculla',
'Byculla East',
'Byculla West',
'CP Tank',
'Chhatrapati Shivaji Terminus',
'Carnac Bunder',
'CBD Belapur',
'CBD Belapur Sector 11',
'Chakala',
'Chandivali',
'Charkop',
'Charni Road',
'Charni Road East',
'Chembur Camp',
'Chembur Colony',
'Chembur East',
'Chembur West',
'Chinch Bandar',
'Chinch Bunder',
'Chinchpokli',
'Chinchpokli East',
'Chinchpokli West',
'Chira Bazaar',
'Chowpatti',
'Chuna Bhatti',
'Churchgate',
'Colaba Causeway',
'Cotton Green',
'Cotton Green West',
'Crawford Market',
'Cuffe Parade',
'Cumbala Hill',
'Currey Road',
'Dadabhai Naoroji Road',
'Dadar East',
'Dadar T T',
'Dadar West',
'Dahisar',
'Dahisar East',
'Dahisar West',
'Dana Bunder',
'Delisle Road',
'Deonar',
'Deonar East',
'Dharavi',
'Dhobhi Talao',
'Dhobi Talao',
'Dockyard',
'Dombivali',
'Dombivali East',
'Dombivali West',
'Dongri',
'Elphinstone Road',
'Flora Fountain',
'Fort',
'Gamdevi',
'Ghansoli',
'Ghatkopar',
'Ghatkopar East',
'Ghatkopar West',
'Ghodbandar Road',
'Girgaon',
'Girgaon Chowpatty',
'Girgaum',
'Goregaon East',
'Goregaon West',
'Govandi',
'Govandi East',
'Govandi West',
'Gowalia Tank',
'Grant Road',
'Grant Road East',
'Grant Road West',
'Green Park Extension',
'Gulalwadi',
'Haji Ali',
'Horiman Circle',
'Hughes Road',
'Hutatma Chowk',
'J B Nagar',
'Jacob Circle',
'Jogeshwari',
'Jogeshwari East',
'Jogeshwari West',
'Juhu Scheme',
'Juhu Tara Road',
'Kalachowki',
'Kala Ghoda',
'Kalamboli',
'Kalbadevi',
'Kalina',
'Kalwa',
'Kalwa West',
'Kalyan',
'Kalyan East',
'Kalyan West',
'Kamothe',
'Kandivali',
'Kanjur Marg East',
'Kanjur Marg West',
'Kanjurmarg',
'Kanjurmarg East',
'Kanjurmarg West',
'Kazi Sayed Street',
'Kemps Corner',
'Khar',
'Khar Danda',
'Khar West',
'Kharghar Sector 12',
'Kharghar Sector 2',
'Kharghar Sector 7',
'Khetwadi',
'Khopoli',
'Kings Circle',
'Kopar Khairane',
'Koper Khraine',
'Andheri Kurla Road',
'Kurla East',
'Kurla West',
'Lal Bahadur Shastri Marg',
'Lal Baug',
'Lalbaug',
'Lamington Road',
'LBS Marg',
'Link Road',
'Lohar Chawl',
'Lokhandwala',
'Parel',
'Lower Parel East',
'Lower Parel West',
'M G Road',
'Mahakali Caves Road',
'Mahalaxmi',
'Mahalaxmi West',
'Mahape',
'Mahim',
'Mahim East',
'Mahim West',
'Malabar Hill',
'Aarey Milk Colony',
'Airport',
'Ambewadi',
'Andheri',
'Asvini',
'Azad Nagar',
'BPT Colony',
'BN Bhavan',
'Bandra',
'Bazargate',
'Bharat Nagar',
'Bhavani Shankar Road',
'CGS Colony',
'Air India Staff Colony',
'Century Mills Worli',
'Chamar Baug',
'Colaba',
'Cotton Exchange',
'Dadar Colony',
'Dadar',
'Danda',
'Dockyard Road',
'Dr Deshmukh Marg',
'Falkland Road',
'Girgaon Mdg',
'Gokhale Road',
'Goregoan',
'Government Colony',
'HMP School',
'Haffkine Institute',
'Haines Road',
'Hanuman Road',
'High Court Building',
'Holiday Camp',
'INS Hamla',
'Central Building',
'Parel Naka',
'Oshiwara',
'Opera House',
'New Yogakshema',
'New Prabhadevi Road',
'N S Patkar Marg',
'Mori Road',
'Mazgaon Road',
'JJ Hospital',
'Juhu',
'Kamathipura',
'Ketkipada',
'Kherwadi',
'Kidwai Nagar',
'Liberty Garden',
'Mazagon Dock',
'Naigaon',
'Mumbai Central',
'Orlem',
'Nagardas Road',
'Madhavbaug',
'Khar Delivery',
'MPT',
'M A Marg',
'Magathane',
'LBSNE College',
'Mazagaon',
'Matunga Railway Workshop',
'Motilal Nagar',
'Nariman Point',
'International Airport',
'Irla',
'Malad',
'Mantralaya',
'Marine Lines',
'Marol Naka',
'Prabhadevi',
'Princess Dock',
'Raj Bhavan',
'Rajendra Nagar',
'Ramwadi',
'Ranade Road',
'Rani Sati Marg',
'SRPF Camp',
'S Savarkar Marg',
'S.K. Nagar',
'Sahar PT Colony',
'Sahargaon',
'Santacruz Central',
'Santacruz P AND T Colony',
'Santacruz',
'Secretariat',
'SEEPZ',
'Sewri',
'Sharma Estate',
'Shroffmahajan',
'Shroff Mahajan',
'Stock Exchange',
'Tajmahal',
'Tajmahal Hotel',
'Tank Road',
'Tardeo',
'Taj Mahal Hotel',
'Thakurdwar',
'Town Hall',
'Tulsiwadi',
'VJB Udyan',
'VK Bhavan',
'VP Road',
'VWTC',
'Vakola',
'Vesava',
'Vidyanagari',
'Vileeparle',
'Vile Parle',
'Wadala',
'Worli',
'Ambarnath West',
'Kharghar',
'spacer',
'spacer'
];
// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$hint = "";
// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = "<li onclick=\"sendToInput(this.innerHTML,'$id', parentNode.id)\">$name</li>";
            } else {
                $hint .= "<li onclick=\"sendToInput(this.innerHTML, '$id', parentNode.id)\">$name</li>";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $hint === "" ? "<li onclick=\"sendToInput(this.innerHTML, '$id',parentNode.id)\">All Mumbai</li>" : $hint;

?>
```

I hope it'll help you

Comment: Is what you’re suggesting actually going to give me an improvement on the number of fields where the functionality works?

Comment: it will work on any number of fields you want to use... it's very compact and extendable it's for your reference you can modify it and use it on your own...

Comment: Thank you for the code you provided.  I did have to make all sorts of changes with it and at times it seemed like I would never get it to work as I needed.  However, eventually I got it set up so that my equivalent of your 'getHint.php' got data from the database that matched the users input and it now all seems to work fine.  I actually have 7 different files like the 'getHint.php' file.  One for each of the fields I needed to have auto-complete working on and they all work as expected.